# Cannot instantiate the type SocketChannel

Tags: java, nio

According to the docs, I can do this:

```
SocketChannel mySocketChannel = new SocketChannel(SelectorProvider.provider());
```

According to JDK I can not.

Simple question: Why am I getting the error in the title?

Comment: "According to the docs, I can do this": No you can't. It doesn't say  that. Anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is `protected`, meaning only inherited classes can access it to inherit its base functionality (notice that `SocketChannel` inherits from `AbstractSelectableChannel`).

To open a `SocketChannel`, use the static `open` method:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
```

See the [SocketChannel Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) and an [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socket-channel.html).